# Multivariate Equation solving

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic

I have the following equation:

```
r^(1 + Rho) - r^Rho (-1 + Mu) - z Rho == 0
```

I searched the list but I couldn't come up with a solution. Any help is appreciated.

How do I solve for `r`?

Comment: See the documentation for `Solve` and `Reduce`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: An analytical solution may not exist.  Try solving the equation numerically.

Answer (score 4):

I know nothing about the range of the data for your problem. Assuming that the values for Rho, Mu and z are real numbers you can gain insight into your problem by combining bbgodfrey's comment with a plot using Manipulate.

For example, if Rho and Mu are known parameters you can see how the solution varies as you change the value of z.

```
Manipulate[

 Column[{
   NSolve[r^(1 + Rho) - r^Rho (-1 + Mu) - z Rho == 0, r],

   Plot[r^(1 + Rho) - r^Rho (-1 + Mu) - z Rho, {r, -5, 5}]
   }],

 {{Rho, 1}, -1, 3, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{Mu, 2}, 1, 4, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{z, 1}, 0, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: 0 < rho <= 1, 0 < r < 20

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful :-)